# WCF webservice not working in LoadRunner

Tags: loadrunner

I have created custom request as per below, We are tryng to replay the wcf webservice as per below, but getting error

```
    enter code here

web_custom_request("ResidentScreening.svc_5", 
        "URL=https://sushil.com/residentscreening/ResidentScreening.svc", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "Resource=0", 
        "RecContentType=text/xml", 
        "Referer=", 
        "Snapshot=t7.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        "EncType=text/xml;charset=UTF-8", 
        "Body=<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n   <soapenv:Header/>\n   <soapenv:Body>\n     <tem:SubmitRequest>\n         <tem:xml>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;ApplicantScreening xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=&quot;ResidentScreening3_0.xsd&quot;&gt;&lt;Request&gt;&lt;PropertyID&gt;&lt;Identification IDType=&quot;Property ID&"
        "quot;&gt;&lt;IDValue&gt;115842&lt;/IDValue&gt;&lt;/Identification&gt;&lt;MarketingName&gt;My Properties&lt;/MarketingName&gt;&lt;/PropertyID&gt;&lt;RequestType&gt;New&lt;/RequestType&gt;&lt;ReportOptions&gt;&lt;ReportName&gt;01&lt;/ReportName&gt;&lt;/ReportOptions&gt;&lt;ReportID/&gt;&lt;OriginatorID&gt;26694&lt;/OriginatorID&gt;&lt;OriginatorTrackingID&gt;reference999&lt;/OriginatorTrackingID&gt;&lt;MarketingSource&gt;Rent.com&lt;/MarketingSource&gt;&lt;UserName&gt;autotest1&lt;/UserName&gt;&lt;"
        "UserPassword&gt;Qctesting3&lt;/UserPassword&gt;&lt;/Request&gt;&lt;LeaseTerms&gt;&lt;MonthlyRent&gt;1400.0000&lt;/MonthlyRent&gt;&lt;LeaseMonths&gt;12&lt;/LeaseMonths&gt;&lt;AffordableLease SubsidyAmount=&quot;200.00&quot;&gt;true&lt;/AffordableLease&gt;&lt;SecurityDeposit&gt;500.00&lt;/SecurityDeposit&gt;&lt;/LeaseTerms&gt;&lt;Applicant&gt;&lt;Other&gt;&lt;CurrentRent&gt;1400.0000&lt;/CurrentRent&gt;&lt;ConsentObtained&gt;YES&lt;/ConsentObtained&gt;&lt;/Other&gt;&lt;Income&gt;&lt;EmploymentStatus"
        "&gt;Employed&lt;/EmploymentStatus&gt;&lt;EmploymentType&gt;Current&lt;/EmploymentType&gt;&lt;EmployerName&gt;Nordstrom&lt;enter code here/EmployerName&gt;&lt;EmploymentGrossIncome&gt;4000.0000&lt;/EmploymentGrossIncome&gt;&lt;EmploymentStartDate&gt;2000-10-15&lt;/EmploymentStartDate&gt;&lt;EmploymentEndDate&gt;2005-01-20&lt;/EmploymentEndDate&gt;&lt;OtherIncomeAmount&gt;1500&lt;/OtherIncomeAmount&gt;&lt;OtherIncomeType&gt;Child Support&lt;/OtherIncomeType&gt;&lt;OtherIncomePeriod&gt;monthly&lt;/OtherIncomePeriod"
        "&gt;&lt;/Income&gt;&lt;AS_Information&gt;&lt;ApplicantIdentifier&gt;t0003544&lt;/ApplicantIdentifier&gt;&lt;ApplicantType&gt;Applicant&lt;/ApplicantType&gt;&lt;GuarantorFor/&gt;&lt;Spouse&gt;t0003545&lt;/Spouse&gt;&lt;MothersMaidenName/&gt;&lt;Birthdate&gt;1965-10-19&lt;/Birthdate&gt;&lt;SocSecNumber&gt;555559999&lt;/SocSecNumber&gt;&lt;DriversLicenseID&gt;027239657&lt;/DriversLicenseID&gt;&lt;DriversLicenseState&gt;GA&lt;/DriversLicenseState&gt;&lt;AddressTerms MoveInDate=&quot;2000-10-10&quot;&"
        "gt;&lt;Address AddressType=&quot;current&quot;&gt;&lt;Address&gt;404 NW Napp St&lt;/Address&gt;&lt;City&gt;De Kalb&lt;/City&gt;&lt;State&gt;TX&lt;/State&gt;&lt;PostalCode&gt;75559&lt;/PostalCode&gt;&lt;CountyName/&gt;&lt;UnparsedAddress&gt;404 NW Napp St&lt;/UnparsedAddress&gt;&lt;Email/&gt;&lt;/Address&gt;&lt;/AddressT**strong text**erms&gt;&lt;AddressTerms MoveInDate=&quot;1989-01-08&quot; MoveOutDate=&quot;2000-10-10&quot;&gt;&lt;Address AddressType=&quot;previous&quot;&gt;&lt;Address&gt;5555 Hollister Avenue"
        "&lt;/Address&gt;&lt;City&gt;Goleta&lt;/City&gt;&lt;State&gt;CA&lt;/State&gt;&lt;PostalCode&gt;93117&lt;/PostalCode&gt;&lt;CountyNameenter code here/&gt;&lt;UnparsedAddress&gt;5555 Hollister Avenue&lt;/UnparsedAddress&gt;&lt;Email/&gt;&lt;/Address&gt;&lt;/AddressTerms&gt;&lt;/AS_Information&gt;&lt;Customers&gt;&lt;Customer&gt;&lt;Identification IDType=&quot;applicant&quot;&gt;&lt;IDValue&gt;t0003544&lt;/IDValue&gt;&lt;/Iden`enter code here`tification&gt;&lt;Name&gt;&lt;FirstName&gt;Stress&lt;/FirstName&gt;&lt;MiddleName/&gt;&lt;"
        "LastName&gt;Test&lt;/LastName&gt;&lt;MaidenName/&gt;&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;Phone PhoneType=&quot;home&quot;&gt;&lt;PhoneNumber&gt;714-982-1000&lt;/PhoneNumber&gt;&lt;/Phone&gt;&lt;Lease&gt;&lt;Identification&gt;&lt;IDValue&gt;t0003545&lt;/IDValue&gt;&lt;/Identification&gt;&lt;ExpectedMoveInDate&gt;2010-12-01&lt;/ExpectedMoveInDate&gt;&lt;ExpectedMoveOutDate&gt;2011-11-30&lt;/ExpectedMoveOutDate&gt;&lt;LeaseFromDate&gt;2010-12-01&lt;/LeaseFromDate&gt;&lt;LeaseToDate&gt;2011-11-30&lt;/LeaseToDate&gt;&lt;"
        "ResponsibleForLease&gt;true&lt;/ResponsibleForLease&gt;&lt;LeaseSignDate&gt;2010-11-15&lt;/LeaseSignDate&gt;&lt;SpecialStatus/&gt;&lt;PaymentAccepted/&gt;&lt;AccountNumber/&gt;&lt;CurrentNumberOccupants Total=&quot;3&quot; Child=&quot;1&quot;&gt;3&lt;/CurrentNumberOccupants&gt;&lt;/Lease&gt;&lt;/Customer&gt;&lt;/Customers&gt;&lt;/Applicant&gt;&lt;Applicant&gt;&lt;Other&gt;&lt;CurrentRent&gt;1400.0000&lt;/CurrentRent&gt;&lt;ConsentObtained&gt;YES&lt;/ConsentObtained&gt;&lt;/Other&gt;&lt;Income&gt;&"
        "lt;EmploymentType&gt;Current&lt;/EmploymentType&gt;&lt;EmployerName&gt;Marsh Law Office&lt;/EmployerName&gt;&lt;EmploymentGrossIncome&gt;5000.0000&lt;/EmploymentGrossIncome&gt;&lt;/Income&gt;&lt;AS_Information&gt;&lt;ApplicantIdentifier&gt;t0003545&lt;/ApplicantIdentifier&gt;&lt;ApplicantType&gt;Applicant&lt;/ApplicantType&gt;&lt;GuarantorFor/&gt;&lt;Spouse&gt;t0003544&lt;/Spouse&gt;&lt;Birthdate&gt;1968-08-14&lt;/Birthdate&gt;&lt;SocSecNumber&gt;444449999&lt;/SocSecNumber&gt;&lt;DriversLicenseID/"
        "&gt;&lt;DriversLicenseState/&gt;&lt;AddressTerms MoveInDate=&quot;2000-10-10&quot;&gt;&lt;Address AddressType=&quot;current&quot;&gt;&lt;Address&gt;404 NW Napp St&lt;/Address&gt;&lt;City&gt;De Kalb&lt;/City&gt;&lt;State&gt;TX&lt;/State&gt;&lt;PostalCode&gt;75559&lt;/PostalCode&gt;&lt;CountyName/&gt;&lt;UnparsedAddress&gt;404 NW Napp St&lt;/UnparsedAddress&gt;&lt;Email/&gt;&lt;/Address&gt;&lt;/AddressTerms&gt;&lt;AddressTerms MoveInDate=&quot;1989-01-08&quot; MoveOutDate=&quot;2000-10-10&quot;&gt;&"
        "lt;Address AddressType=&quot;previous&quot;&gt;&lt;Address&gt;5555 Hollister Avenue&lt;/Address&gt;&lt;City&gt;Goleta&lt;/City&gt;&lt;State&gt;CA&lt;/State&gt;&lt;PostalCode&gt;93117&lt;/PostalCode&gt;&lt;CountyName/&gt;&lt;UnparsedAddress&gt;5555 Hollister Avenue&lt;/UnparsedAddress&gt;&lt;Email/&gt;&lt;/Address&gt;&lt;/AddressTerms&gt;&lt;/AS_Information&gt;&lt;Customers&gt;&lt;Customer&gt;&lt;Identification IDType=&quot;applicant&quot;&gt;&lt;IDValue&gt;t0003545&lt;/IDValue&gt;&lt;/"
        "Identification&gt;&lt;Name&gt;&lt;FirstName&gt;SpouseOf&lt;/FirstName&gt;&lt;MiddleName/&gt;&lt;LastName&gt;Test&lt;/LastName&gt;&lt;MaidenName&gt;Thompson&lt;/MaidenName&gt;&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;Lease&gt;&lt;Identification&gt;&lt;IDValue&gt;t0003545&lt;/IDValue&gt;&lt;/Identification&gt;&lt;ExpectedMoveInDate&gt;2010-12-01&lt;/ExpectedMoveInDate&gt;&lt;ExpectedMoveOutDate&gt;2011-11-30&lt;/ExpectedMoveOutDate&gt;&lt;LeaseFromDate&gt;2010-12-01&lt;/LeaseFromDate&gt;&lt;LeaseToDate&gt;2011-11-30&lt;/"
        "LeaseToDate&gt;&lt;ResponsibleForLease&gt;true&lt;/ResponsibleForLease&gt;&lt;LeaseSignDate&gt;2010-11-15&lt;/LeaseSignDate&gt;&lt;SpecialStatus/&gt;&lt;PaymentAccepted/&gt;&lt;AccountNumber/&gt;&lt;CurrentNumberOccupants Total=&quot;3&quot; Child=&quot;1&quot;&gt;3&lt;/CurrentNumberOccupants&gt;&lt;/Lease&gt;&lt;/Customer&gt;&lt;/Customers&gt;&lt;/Applicant&gt;&lt;CustomRecords&gt;&lt;Record&gt;&lt;Name&gt;User Defined 1&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;Value&gt;ClientRef 1&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Record&gt;&lt;Record&"
        "gt;&lt;Name&gt;User Defined 2&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;Value&gt;ClientRef 1&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Record&gt;&lt;Record&gt;&lt;Name&gt;Unit Number&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;Value&gt;100&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Record&gt;&lt;/CustomRecords&gt;&lt;/ApplicantScreening&gt;</tem:xml>\n      </tem:SubmitRequest>\n   </soapenv:Body>\n</soapenv:Envelope>", 
        LAST);

    lr_message(lr_eval_string("Response XML is \n{response}"));
    return 0;
```

Action.c(102): Error -26612: HTTP Status-Code=500 (Internal Server Error). please share if any working sample available.

Comment: have done this by running SOAP UI and the same time Load runner is capturung the soap request from soap UI tool.this is one way.But we verified the service request through SOAP UI which is working fine

Comment: 2nd way - tried creating web service call from Load runner but no luck.

Comment: i am getting below error -<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body>ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be becaAction.c(102):use of either a ontractmismatch(mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a biAction.c(102):   nding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiv
Action.c(102): er have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Mess
Action.c(102):     age, Transport, None).</faultstring></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>

Answer (score 0):

Record twice, compare.  You will also need to add appropriate soap headers via web_add_header()